# interpolation - graphical quality evaluation

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, python-3.x, score

I try to compare different interpolation models quality and I'm looking for a graphical tool to do that.

Application case: I'm not familiar with intepolation using neural networks. I decide to test it on a dataset having 5 inputs for 1 output: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Airfoil+Self-Noise# And to prospect it quickly, I used Orange canvas that integrate the `sklearn` Multi layer perceptron. I'm surprised to see that *"bigger the network is, better is the result"*. And I would like to investigate it.

Basic metrics are `MSE`, `RMSE`, `MAE`, `R2`. But it is a too global approach. Maybe the interpolation is good on a specific range and not somewhere else, and I would like to see that. In `sklearn` there is also the *"Explained variance score"* metric that is close to what I'm looking for. But I was imagining a simple *"quality curve"* between estimated values vs original values. I'm certainaly missing something. That's why I need your help.

Can you share some practice, tools, or keywords to help me in visual regression quality understanding ?

Comment: you can plot all the metrics by piecewise-evaluation over small intervals, or simply plot the point-wise error to get an idea of the fitting achieved